# How to block/prevent deleting a Chrome Profile?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

(Not sure which of the two sites is best to post this, so I am trying both. If this is inappropriate, please advise.)
https://superuser.com/questions/1812441/how-to-block-prevent-deleting-a-chrome-for-windows-profile
(so please post replies on the other site above first)

I'm trying to prevent the ability to delete a Chrome profile.

My thinking is to block/prevent opening the Chrome (for Windows) Profile Picker.

I use a browser extension (LeechBlock, though this is not key) that can allow blocking the new Chrome Profile Picker main window via the addressbar, by using a regular expression ^chrome://profile-picker.

The problem is you can still access the profile picker if you select/click the profile icon then select/click the gear icon for "Manage Profiles", or click the three dots, highlight the user profile icon, and select/click "Manager Other Profiles" in the submenu; in both cases this brings up a separate pop-up window for the Profile Picker, but it lacks the addressbar.

Does anyone know how to determine the addressbar reference for this window, or some other means to block this pop-up window?

Or any other ideas on how to prevent deleting a profile?

(Using Chrome for Windows).

P.S. I am only using and only have admin access to consumer level Windows, not Pro, Enterprise, Educational, etc.)